# Testing actions throws error mockImplementationOnce is not a function

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs2, vuex

I am new to Vue testing. My app is using Vuex store and I managed to test the getters and the mutations by ready the amazing book by Edd Yerburgh [Testing Vue.js Applications](https://www.manning.com/books/testing-vue-js-applications). But I can't make the actions work yet.

The structure I have is as follows:

```
store folder
  - mutations.js
  - actions.js
  - getters.js
```

This is the code for the login dispatch action:

```
async login( { commit, dispatch }, payload ) {
    try {
      const username = payload.user
      const passwordHash = payload.password
      const hashFunction = payload.hashFunction
      if (!username || !passwordHash || !hashFunction) throw Error

      await axios.post(
        `${API_URL}/${AppEndpoints.login}`,
        {
          user: username,
          password: passwordHash,
          hashFunction: hashFunction,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        }
      )
      .then( function( response ) {
        if (response.data && response.data.data && response.data.success && !response.data.error) {
          commit(MUTATION.SET_USER_NAME, username)
          commit(MUTATION.SET_USER_PASSWORD, passwordHash)
          commit(MUTATION.SET_USER_HASH_FUNCTION, hashFunction)
          })
        } else {
          return Promise.reject(Error(response?.data?.errorMsg || response?.data || "Error: authentication failed"))
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        return Promise.reject(Error(error.response?.data?.errorMsg || error.response?.data || error.message || "Error: authentication failed"))
      } );
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch('clearUserAndPassword')
      commit(MUTATION.SET_ERROR_MESSAGE, error.message)
    }
  }
```

And this is the test I implemented:

```
it( 'should dispatch login action with full payload', async function () {
    const payload = {
      user: "test",
      password: "test",
      hashFunction: "sha256"
    };
    actions.login.mockImplementationOnce( () => {
      return Promise.resolve();
    } );

    const commit = jest.fn();
    await actions.login( { commit }, payload );
    await flushPromises();
    expect( commit ).toHaveBeenCalledWith( MUTATION.SET_USER_NAME, payload.user );
  } );
```

When I try to run the tests script, I get this error:

```
_actions.default.login.mockImplementationOnce is not a function
TypeError: _actions.default.login.mockImplementationOnce is not a function
```

I think I'm following the steps in the book, but obviously I am missing something here. Any help is appreciated

**Edit 1:**
Thanks to Anh Tuan I modified the test. Now the error I get is something very different.
This is how the test looks now:

```
import axios from "axios";
import flushPromises from 'flush-promises'
import actions from "@/store/actions";
import * as MUTATION from "@/store/mutation-types";

let url = '';
let body = {};

jest.mock( "axios", () => ( {
  post: jest.fn( ( _url, _body ) => {
    return new Promise( ( resolve ) => {
      url = _url
      body = _body
      resolve( true )
    } )
  } )
} ) );

describe( 'Store actions', () => {
  it( 'should dispatch login action with full payload', async function () {
    const response = {
      data: []
    };
    axios.post.mockResolvedValue( response );

    const payload = {
      user: "test",
      password: "test",
      hashFunction: "sha256"
    };
    const commit = jest.fn();
    await actions.login( { commit }, payload );

    await flushPromises();

    expect( axios.post ).toHaveBeenCalledTimes( 1 );
    expect( commit ).toHaveBeenCalledWith( MUTATION.SET_USER_NAME, payload.user );
  } );
} )
```

But this is the error I'm getting now:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'request')
```

It is because of this line in the store index:

```
export const requestInterceptor = config => {
  config.signal = abortingControllers?.route?.signal
  config.withCredentials = true
  return config
}
axios.interceptors.request.use(requestInterceptor)
```

What do I do in this case? Should I also mock this interceptor?

Comment: If you're testing your login action, you shouldn't mock it. Otherwise the implementation is not tested at all. Instead you should rather mock your axios call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to @Anh Tuan Nguyen I could modify the test I was implementing, and now it is working. I hope other people that are new can find this useful.

This is how it finally looks:

```
import axios from "axios";
import flushPromises from 'flush-promises'
import actions from "@/store/actions";
import * as MUTATION from "@/store/mutation-types";

let url = '';
let body = {};

jest.mock( "axios", () => ( {
  post: jest.fn( ( _url, _body ) => {
    return new Promise( ( resolve ) => {
      url = _url
      body = _body
      resolve( true )
    } )
  } ),
  interceptors: {
    request: {
      use: jest.fn()
    }
  }
} ) );

describe( 'Store actions', () => {
  it( 'should dispatch login action with full payload', async function () {
    expect.assertions( 4 );

    const response = {
      data: {
        data: [],
        success: true
      }
    };
    axios.post.mockResolvedValue( response );

    const payload = {
      user: "test",
      password: "test",
      hashFunction: "sha256"
    };
    const commit = jest.fn();
    const dispatch = jest.fn();
    await actions.login( { commit, dispatch }, payload );

    await flushPromises();

    expect( axios.post ).toHaveBeenCalledTimes( 1 );
    expect( commit ).toHaveBeenCalledWith( MUTATION.SET_USER_NAME, payload.user );
    expect( commit ).toHaveBeenCalledWith( MUTATION.SET_USER_PASSWORD, payload.password );
    expect( commit ).toHaveBeenCalledWith( MUTATION.SET_USER_HASH_FUNCTION, payload.hashFunction );
  } );
})
```